# Eulogy : Praise , what would be an equivalent to "criticize"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

> Usually a eulogy makes the dead person sound a lot more impressive
>   than they really were.

- A couple of less common synonyms for this kind  of "praise the dead"
  speech are panegyric and encomium.

> Is there a similar noun (phrase) when the dead person is chastised and
>   critised?

Comment: 'Speak ill of'.

Comment: Note that _panegyric_ and _encomium_ are just praising speeches—they don’t imply that the subject being praised is dead. Chastising and criticising someone who’s dead could be (perhaps somewhat exaggeratedly) described as _dancing on their grave_.

Comment: I think that is a reasonable extension of the expression, @JanusBahsJacquet. I'm not sure, but I think its general meaning is *get revenge by outliving a person*. Showing up at his funeral, and dropping a few derogatory bombs on his memory seems true to the word picture. God forbid, I would never do it myself though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious negative counterpart of *eulogy* would be *dyslogy*.  *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) doesn't list that word, although it does have an entry for *dyslogistic*:

> **dyslogistic** *adj* (1812) : UNCOMPLIMENTARY

On the other hand, *dyslogy* does appear in the [Collins Online Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dyslogy), with the following definitions:

> **dyslogy** *noun* 1. the fact of criticizing or condemning 2. the aspects suggested in processing information and liable to be at the root of mistakes made in thought processes

If *dyslogy* seems a bit arcane or unsettled for your purposes, you might consider (besides the options ScotM suggests) the words *malediction* ("CURSE, EXECRATION"), *execration* ("the act of cursing or denouncing"), and *denunciation* ("an act of denouncing; *esp* : a public condemnation"). All of the parenthetical definitions in this paragraph are from the Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary.

Comment: Thumbs up- negative counterpart of eulogy would be dyslogy. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Praise the dead" : ***laudatory***,  "criticize the dead": ***condemnatory***.

*I think there is a measure of glorification that a death activates. 
When someone dies, we’re almost forced to see the person in a positive light and say nothing that may reflect badly on the person.*

Answer (score 2):

In light of the cultural objection to criticizing the dead, most people find a way to deliver

a *[left-handed compliment:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/left-handed+compliment)*

> noun phrase
>
> Praise that is subtle dispraise; reluctant and dubious praise:
>
> *Telling that amusing story of his drunken tomfoolery was a left-handed complement.*

Depending on the severity of the criticism and nature of the objections other labels may fit:

*[Animadversion:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/animadversion)*

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN] formal
>
> 1.0 Criticism or censure:
>
> *Her animadversion against her dead father was understandable even if it was awkward.*

[*Aspersion*:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aspersion)

> NOUN
>
> (usually aspersions)
>
> An attack on the reputation or integrity of someone or something:
>
> *It is generally considered rude to cast aspersions on the dead while everyone is mourning deeply.*

*[Opprobrium:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opprobrium)*

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> 1.0 Harsh criticism or censure:
>
> *His evil deeds earned Hitler almost universal opprobrium.*

Because it only benefits the critic, many people would consider public criticism of the dead [*cavil*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cavil) until some time of mourning has passed:

> NOUN
>
> A petty or unnecessary objection.
>
> *All the cavil is water under the bridge.*

Comment: Well done!  I'd give this 2+ if I could!

Comment: *Denunciation* and *calumny* also have their uses.

Comment: I considered calumny, but it has a strong connotation of falsehood. Denunciation could work.

Comment: "left handed compliment"- thanks for the word, deserves a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

Another word is *[dispraise](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dispraise&oq=Dispraise&aqs=chrome..69i57.3712983j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)*:

noun :
1.
censure; criticism;
"this engraving has on occasion elicited dispraise for Raphael."

verb :
1.
express censure or criticism of (someone);
"men cannot praise Dryden without dispraising Coleridge."